# How does encode and decode 64 figure out that the last few zeros are mere padding?

Tags: base64

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-5.0

It says

> If an integral number of 3-byte groups does not exist, the remaining
> bytes are effectively padded with zeros to form a complete group. In
> this example, the value of the last byte is hexadecimal FF. The first
> 6 bits are equal to decimal 63, which corresponds to the base-64 digit
> "/" at the end of the output, and the next 2 bits are padded with
> zeros to yield decimal 48, which corresponds to the base-64 digit,
> "w". The last two 6-bit values are padding and correspond to the
> valueless padding character, "=".

Now,

Imagine that the byte array I send is

0

So, only one byte, namely 0

That one byte will be padded right into 000 right?

So now, we will have something like 0=== as the encoding because it takes 4 characters in base 64 encoding to encode 3 bytes.

Now, we gonna decode that.

How do we know that the original byte isn't 00, or 000, but just 0?

I must be missing something here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, so not an answer, bu I think you are basically in the *single M* example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples). From the first 0 byte, the base64 will generate two A characters. To fill the remaining bits of the second A, there will be 4 zeros padded. Then two remaining blocks are empty. At decoding, it can assert that the last A block is incomplete thanks to the = padding and from "AA" it can build back the single 0 byte.

Comment: Oh I see. So 0->AA== 00->AAA= and 000 will be AAAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So now, we will have something like 0=== as the encoding

3 padding characters is illegal. This would mean 6 bit plus padding.

And then 0 as a byte value is `A` in Base64, so it would be `AA==`.

So the first A has the first 6 bits of the 0 byte, the second A contributes the 2 remaining 0 bits for your byte, and then there are just 4 0 bits plus the padding left, not enough for a second byte.

> How do we know that the original byte isn't 00, or 000, but just 0?

`AA==` has only 12 bits (6 bits per character) so it can only encode 1 Byte => 0

`AAA=` has 18 bits, enough for 2 bytes => 00

`AAAA` has 24 bits = 3 bytes => 000